# Android - notifyDataSetChanged not being called after OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I need to refresh a Viewpager that's inside an ArrayAdapter. When the user clicks a Button, the List being passed to Viewpager is updated and notifyDataSetChanged is called.

But nothing happens. How can this be made, please? It's been 2 days I'm trying all sorts of things. Please, help me. Thanks.
[This image Shows a little more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Ba4.png)

```
public class MyAdapter extends extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>{
   private ViewPager mViewPager;
   private ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
//...

   public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

   final MyObject myObject =getItem(position);

//this part works
//viewpager loads the images
   mList.clear();
   mList.addAll(myObject.getListOfImgUri);
   mViewPagerAdapter = new 
   ViewPagerAdapter(mContext, mList); 
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
   //this part never gets called
   mList.addAll(myObject.getSecondListOfImgUri());


        }
       });
 }

}
```

EDIT: after following advice, this is the obtained result:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

       //previously, this part was never  called

        mList.clear();
       mList.addAll(myObject.getSecondListOfImgUri());

       Log.d(tag, mList.get(0));//result: Logs new Image
       mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
           });
     }

    }
```

And, Inside ViewPager:

```
@NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            destroyItem(container, position,mViewGroup );
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            // mViewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, container, false);

            mViewGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item,container, false);
            ImageView imageView = mViewGroup.findViewById(R.id.theImg);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(mListData.get(position)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true).into(imageView);
            container.addView(mViewGroup);
            Log.d(tag, "instantiateItem: " +mListData.get(0));//result: Logs new Image



            return mViewGroup;
        }
```

But only a blank page is showing inside Viewpager.

Comment: make sure you have your updated data in `myObject.getListOfImgUri`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Sorry, could you please elaborate? I'm updating the list being passed to ViewPager inside OnclickListener. Why isn't  this enough?

Comment: if it's from firebase, use incomplete listener etc

Comment: I am using Firebase Listener. It gets the images I need. If you take a look at the pic I've posted, you'll see that ViewPager shows the pictures from getListOfImgUri(). But notifyDataSetChanged doesn't get called. I know it populates the ViewPager with getSecondListOfImgUri() because Log shows different images from getListOfImgUri().

Answer (score 0):

Add `notifydatasetChanged()` method to the `mViewPagerAdapter`. Currently the `MyAdapter` is getting the `notifydatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: Hi, I did that, and the new images are blank. I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>{
   private ViewPager mViewPager;
   private ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
//...

   public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

   final MyObject myObject =getItem(position);

//this part works
//viewpager loads the images
   mList.clear();
   mList.addAll(myObject.getListOfImgUri);
   mViewPagerAdapter = new 
   ViewPagerAdapter(mContext, mList); 
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
   //this part never gets called
   mList.addAll(myObjecy.getSecondListOfImgUri);

   **mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

        }
       });
 }

}
```

Comment: I did it. It loads blank images after the already loaded images. Log inside both OnclickListener and Viewpager shows that the list at all positions contain valid images, though. When I tried to first clear mList Inside OnClick, then add Second List, it never called the second load. Only when I created a new Instance of ViewPager inside Onclick, set it to the already created Adapter, and called notify again. And the result was only Blank Images, with Log of valid images insde the Lists. Oh, I also called removeView inside ViewPager, first thing on getView.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I added DestroyItem() inside Viewpager, first thing in instantiateItem. I edited my question, to make it clearer.

Comment: try new public void updateList(List<Receipt> mList) {
    mList= mList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void updateList(List<Receipt> mList) {
    receiptlist.clear();
    receiptlist.addAll(mList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}